# Обособление сравнительного оборота с наречием «точь-в-точь»

Tags: сравнительный-оборот

Похожее предложение есть у Розенталя (с наречием *почти*), но, по-моему, сравнительный оборот в этих случаях лучше обособить:

*Было светло,  **точь-в-точь как днем***. *Было светло, **почти как днем***.

Розенталь, пункт 4(5) http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147

Как можно объяснить выбор правильного варианта (с обособлением или без обособления)?

Comment: Это вы здесь, а я собираюсь исчезнуть.  Заходите чаще!  И у вас еще есть время ответить на вопрос про "главное".

Comment: Не будьте столь меркантильны. Мы - волонтеры, помогаем людям. их благодарность и есть награда. К тому же квалификацию можете потерять без ежедневной тренировки.

Comment: А где вы видели платный форум, на котором можно заработать больше 10 рублей в день. А здесь для вас бесплатная тренировка, где еще есть такие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классный у Розенталя пример. С таким не сталкивался.

У него оборот является обстоятельством к слову "светло":
*Было светло [насколько светло?] почти как днем.*
Здесь оборот выступает на первый план. А то, что было светло, скорее всего, или известно, или и так ясно. На слове "светло" нет ударения.

У Розенталя нередко говорится о разного рода связках, которые отменяют запятую. Здесь "почти" связывает.

Если поставить запятую, то это может быть либо сравнением, либо присоединением (больше похоже). То есть не однозначно получится.

"Точь-в-точь" длинновато для такой роли, разве что с натяжкой.